# Horizontal swipe using co-ordinates in appium java client 7.0.0

Tags: android, appium, java-client

I am trying to swipe horizontally in appium android - java-client 7.0.0. It doesn't work

```
//Horizontal Swipe by percentages
public void horizontalSwipeByPercentages(double startPercentage, double endPercentage, double anchorPercentage) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.width * endPercentage);

    new TouchAction(driver)
        .press(PointOption.point(endPoint, startPoint))
        .waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600)))
        .moveTo(PointOption.point(startPoint, endPoint))
        .release().perform();
}
```

Called as below in my test.
horizontalSwipeByPercentages(0.2,0.5,0.5);

By doing this, code is pulling notification bar

Comment: could You please double check whether proposed solution below is working?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@akbar, from [experitest example provided](https://appium.experitest.com/t/how-to-use-android-swipe-on-eclipse-java/789/3) could You please try out

```
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
ta.press(434, 468).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).moveTo(471, 312).release().perform();
```

====================================

**or alternatively (approach #2)** 
considering [this example](https://discuss.appium.io/t/left-or-right-swipe-not-working-in-appium-for-android-app/14515/3)

```
public static void swipeHorizontal(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.width * finalPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor)
    .waitAction(duration)
    .moveTo(endPoint, anchor)
    .release()
    .perform();

    //In documentation they mention moveTo coordinates are relative to initial ones, but thats not happening. When it does we need to use the function below
    //new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endPoint-startPoint,0).release().perform();
}
```

And calling it with the value from your topic would be:

```
swipeHorizontal(driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,3000);
```

Notice the comments about absolute/relative values

===================================

And another approach **(approach #3)**

Take a look into [this one thread](https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-scroll-swipe-using-latest-java-client/26131)

**Appium of version 1.9.1 and client upgrading to 7.0.0** swipe worked with the following code (vertical swipe. for horizontal swipe- change `getHeight()` to `getWidth()` from 'dimensions' ):

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
PointOption p1= new PointOption();
Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
int h1 = screenHeightStart.intValue();
Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
int h2 = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
action.press(PointOption.point(0,h1))
.waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600)))
.moveTo(PointOption.point(0, h2))
.release()
.perform();
```

That worked perfectly for me.
Hope this helps,

Best regards,
Eugene

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for your inputs
All the above samples pull notification bar

Do I need to use press(x,y) or press(PointOption.point(x,y))

Comment: @Akbar, please try out   ```press(PointOption pressOptions)```   
e.g  https://kobiton.com/book/chapter-11-automating-gestures/    =>  *touchAction.press(point(x,y))*

Comment: @Akbar, please feel free to accept my answer if this works for  You. Thankful in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe resolve your problem.

```
new TouchAction(driver)
            .longPress(start_x,start_y)
            .waitAction()
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(end_x,end_y)
            .release().perform();
    }
```